# Android usage PreferenceFragment in old platforms

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences

In my app I need provide this screen for tablets.

[image]

So when I choose `Setings` from `ListFragment` I need add appropriative fragment to activity e.g. `PreferenceFragment`, but there is no `PreferenceFragment` in `support library`.

Is there any "legal" way to use `PreferenceFragment` in platforms olter than 11 API level? Of cause there are projects on GitHub, which adding `PreferenceFragment` to `android.support.v4.app.`. For example [that](https://gist.github.com/cbeyls/7475726).

But usage of project like this is a good idea or not? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

However I use `sw` to provide differend screens and it starts from the 3.2 version e.g. API level 13 and PreferenceFragment starts from API level 11.
So as far as I see I think that will be enought provide `PreferenceFragment` for tablets and `PreferenceActivity` for handsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess these are what you might be looking for:

[PreferenceFragment-Compat](https://github.com/Machinarius/PreferenceFragment-Compat)

[Android-support-v4-preferencefragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment)